# Display book hierarchy of one organic group with Panels

Tags: views, panels, organic-groups, nodes

I am using organic groups for a tutorial website.

I have one group for each tutorial. For example,

- Java Group
- C++ Group
- Python Group
  etc.

For each Group, I have a tutorial using the book module of drupals (several chapters, etc).
I also have several others contents for each group (for example posts, etc).

I am using views and panels to display the content of each group.
For example, I am using the OG members view to display all the members of the current group.

There is an OG content view but it displays ALL the content of the group.
I just want to display the book associated to the group with the book hierarchy (as with the block navigation).
Any idea of how to do that ? 
Thank you.